# Comparing values between rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table of objects that has values associated to it. The value depends on what model is being used to calculate it.

To model this relation I created a connection table with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE object_value
(
  object_id integer NOT NULL,
  model character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  value integer,
  CONSTRAINT object_value_pkey PRIMARY KEY (object_id, model),
  CONSTRAINT object_value_object_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (leg_id)
  REFERENCES object (id) MATCH SIMPLE
)
```

Some example data:

```
object_id; model; value
116288;"model_2.2.3";7028
116288;"model_2.2.4";7028
116289;"model_2.2.3";5535
116289;"model_2.2.4";5530
116290;"model_2.2.3";3529
116290;"model_2.2.4";3530
```

I have been querying this table to look for differences in model calculations as follow:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (object_id) *
          FROM object_value AS a INNER JOIN object_value AS b USING(object_id)
          WHERE a.value!=b.value;
```

This has been working fine since I have only two different models but when adding data from a third model version the query will not work as intended. And joing the the table to itself again will leave me with the same issue when adding a fourth model.

Is there a different concept of comparing values between rows that I'm not thinking of?

Comment: _when adding data from a third model version the query will not work as intended_ , need more clarification on this ?

Comment: Where does `leg_alertness` come from?

Comment: That was a copy/paste misstake, it should be object_value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the differences in one row using aggregates, e.g.:

```
insert into object_value values -- third model added
(116290, 'model_2.2.5', 3600);

select 
    object_id, 
    string_agg(model, ' : ') as model, 
    string_agg(value::text, ' : ') as value
from object_value
group by 1
order by 1

 object_id |                  model                  |       value        
-----------+-----------------------------------------+--------------------
    116288 | model_2.2.3 : model_2.2.4               | 7028 : 7028
    116289 | model_2.2.3 : model_2.2.4               | 5535 : 5530
    116290 | model_2.2.3 : model_2.2.4 : model_2.2.5 | 3529 : 3530 : 3600
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Thanks! I combining your answer with @gordon-linoff 's having clause was what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find objects where the model values differ, then use aggregation, not joins:

```
select ov.object_id
from object_value ov
group by ov.object_id
having min(ov.value) <> max(ov.value);
```

If you want to see the list of models and/or values, then you can use `string_agg()`.  If you want to see all the details, then a similar query using window functions should work:

```
select ov.*
from (select ov.*,
             min(ov.value) over (partition by object_id) as minvalue,
             max(ov.value) over (partition by object_id) as maxvalue
      from object_value ov
     ) ov
where minvalue <> maxvalue;
```

Comment: Perfect! I ended up using the following to get me precisly what I want:

    select 
    object_id, 
        string_agg(model, ' : ') as model, 
        string_agg(value::text, ' : ') as value
    from object_value 
    group by object_id having min(value) <> max(value);